# Joining a value with a string in MySQL search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm basically looking to join a search value with a custom string in order to query a database.

My query looks something like this (of course the part that has +'_New' is incorrect)

```
SELECT * FROM books b 
WHERE 
b.condition = 'Used' 
AND b.price < (SELECT b2.price FROM books b2 WHERE b2.id = b.isbn+'_New')
```

In the above query I am trying to return all the used books that are cheaper than their 'new' counter parts, the most efficient way to do this search is to specify the correct id (I checked it's actually 10 times faster).

I don't know how to join a string to the isbn value, any help woul be appreciated.

Comment: A simple research could have lead to solution!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I did research, but I didn't know the term used was Concatenate, it took me longer to type this. There was no need for your rude condescending comment.

Comment: Sorry,I didnt mean to be rude. Self learning is what I was trying to stress upon. As that would help you to solve most of the problems, rather seeking help to solve one like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CONCAT`

example

```
WHERE b2.id = CONCAT(b.isbn, "_New")
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

You should join them by using [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT * FROM books b 
WHERE 
b.condition = 'Used' 
AND b.price < (SELECT b2.price FROM books b2 WHERE b2.id = CONCAT(b.isbn, '_New'))
```